# IPtables dropping packets I can't see with tcpdump and I don't know why?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, firewall, iptables

My IPtables rules are blocking `apt update` for example:

```
root@vpn:~# apt update
Ign:1 https://pkgs.tailscale.com/stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:1 https://pkgs.tailscale.com/stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:1 https://pkgs.tailscale.com/stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:5 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Err:1 https://pkgs.tailscale.com/stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'pkgs.tailscale.com'
Ign:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:5 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:5 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Err:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'de.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'de.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'de.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:5 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'de.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Temporary failure re                                                                                                                                                                                                                      solving 'de.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Temporary fa                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ilure resolving 'de.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Temporary                                                                                                                                                                                                                       failure resolving 'de.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  Temporary f                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ailure resolving 'de.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch https://pkgs.tailscale.com/stable/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Temporary failu                                                                                                                                                                                                                      re resolving 'pkgs.tailscale.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
root@vpn:~#
```

Which is using 80 or 443 outgoing, and uses state `ESTABLISHED` in `INPUT` Chain as far as I know.

These are my rules:

```
root@vpn:~# iptables -S
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

root@vpn:~# iptables -L -nv
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 320 packets, 22536 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 5039  226K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
  127 22352 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 80 packets, 4160 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 8759 packets, 869K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
root@vpn:~#
```

In tcpdump I can't see nearly any traffic while these rules are enabled, I can't see the server even Trying to reach anything while trying to use `apt`.

Anything thats dropped by kernel I can't see in tcpdump or logs.

```
25 packets captured
373 packets received by filter
292 packets dropped by kernel
```

Literally, the only traffic tcdump shows me, while these rules are in place, is the traffic to my PC over Port 22 SSH, and some ARP Messages, nothing else.

If I set all policies to `ACCEPT` and flush all chains, everything works and I don’t get it.

**EDIT 3**
Added a new Animation/Gif/Mp4 Combinig Both Tests, with an added tcpdump Split View. My Other Gif's are Therefore not needed anymore and i Removed Edit1 and 2 from this Post.
[Firewall_tcpdump_split_view](https://i.imgur.com/thA88pv.mp4)

**EDIT 4**

Here are my Routes, since I've been asked for this. There is no Docker running or anything else. The VPN is Down thew whole time. Please ask for more detais if more details are needed.

But you need to tell me which details are needed because I don't know.

```
root@vpn:~# ip route
default via 192.168.178.1 dev ens18 proto static
192.168.178.0/24 dev ens18 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.178.49
```

Comment: Are you sure they are being dropped _by iptables_ specifically? Normally tcpdump picks up packets before iptables, not after.

Comment: YES i am 100% Sure, because as i mentioned, if a set the Policys to ACCEPT and Flush all Chains, it WORKDS!!!

Comment: The `Temporary failure resolving '...'` messages are DNS errors, not HTTP. Simplify your test - try something like `dig archive.ubuntu.com` with/without your rules and see what comes back.

Comment: Please also take a moment to breath... please don't swear and try to compose your question clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need the following rule:

```
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

This is likely because you have the systemd-resolved local DNS stub listener listed as the (only) nameserver in your `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Without the above rule, you won't be able to reach servers running on your own host, because unlike communication with another host, the `NEW` / initiating traffics are received by your own host itself. Therefore, it's not sufficient to just whitelist the `ESTABLISHED` traffics in the `INPUT` chain in this case.

You might notice that DNS resolution is not down for every program though, because when you have `systemd-resolved` running, nameserver(s) listed in your `/etc/resolv.conf` is not the only thing that can be used to get the job done. See [systemd-resolved.service(8)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd-resolved.service.html) for more details.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you very much that is true. But why is that true? That's not the Ubuntu 22 LTS Default Setting, is it? And i can't remember to have changed this... odd...

Comment: You mean like the use of systemd-resolved (and the stub listener)? I have no idea. I've been on Arch all the time and using networkd+resolved since ages ago.